# Class akka.actor.TypedActor$MethodCall can not access a member of class JobManager with modifiers "public abstract"

Tags: java, scala, akka

I'm using Akka typed actors in Java.  I have a `BatchManager` that is the interface with the controller, and a `JobManager` that creates some workers and executes a job.  JobManager looks like

```
interface JobManager {
    public Future<String> execute();
    public Future<AwaitableBatchStatusResponse> awaitCompletion();
    public Future<BatchStatusResponse> getStatus();
    public Future<String> reloadFailures();
    public void jobComplete(JobMessage message);
}
```

where `Future` is `scala.concurrent.Future`.  The implementation class overrides all of these methods, in particular

```
class JobManagerImpl implements JobManager {
    public JobManagerImpl() { 
        System.out.println("JobManagerImpl constructor start");
        // do some stuff
        System.out.println("JobMangerImpl constructor end");
    }

    @Override
    public Future<String> execute() {
        System.out.println("start execute on jobmanager");
        // do some stuff
        System.out.println("end execute in jobmanager");
        return Futures.successful("blah");
    }
}
```

The `JobManager` is being constructed successfully (insofar as I'm printing out "JobMangerImpl constructor end" at the end of the constructor).  However, the `BatchManager` then calls `execute` on the new `JobManager`, and I'm being told that the message is going to dead letters (along with the error in the thread title - stack trace is below).  My printlns in JobManagerImpl#execute aren't being run.

```
Enqueue job: d90c4d58-3142-48cd-8f3e-96e75d4ca7d1
Execute job: d90c4d58-3142-48cd-8f3e-96e75d4ca7d1
start create job manager in poll
JobManagerImpl constructor start : d90c4d58-3142-48cd-8f3e-96e75d4ca7d1
JobMangerImpl constructor end
end create jobManager in poll
begin execute in batchmanager
end execute in batchmanager
JobManagerImpl constructor start : d90c4d58-3142-48cd-8f3e-96e75d4ca7d1
JobMangerImpl constructor end
[INFO] [07/15/2015 15:36:07.088] [PerformanceAsync-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://PerformanceAsync/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://PerformanceAsync/user/StandardJobManager#1902186473] to Actor[akka://PerformanceAsync/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[ERROR] [07/15/2015 15:36:07.089] [PerformanceAsync-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://PerformanceAsync/user/StandardJobManager/StandardJobManager:d90c4d58-3142-48cd-8f3e-96e75d4ca7d1:JobManager] Class akka.actor.TypedActor$MethodCall can not access a member of class com.async.JobManager with modifiers "public abstract"
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class akka.actor.TypedActor$MethodCall can not access a member of class com.async.JobManager with modifiers "public abstract"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:101)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:295)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:287)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:476)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$MethodCall.apply(TypedActor.scala:145)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$TypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(TypedActor.scala:311)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$TypedActor.withContext(TypedActor.scala:299)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$TypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(TypedActor.scala:306)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at akka.actor.TypedActor$TypedActor.aroundReceive(TypedActor.scala:246)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am stumped - I've overridden all of the `JobManager` methods with public methods, so why isn't Akka able to reach them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is that I was creating the `JobManagerImpl` in a static inner class of `BatchManagerImpl` - this inner class was in a weird sort of limbo where `TypedActor.get(TypedActor.context())` didn't throw an exception for being used outside of a TypedActor context, but anything instantiated this way was internally broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, that the TypedActor method call is using the class `JobManager` instead of `JobManagerImpl`.

Though you/Akka had instantiated `JobManagerImpl` as we can see the constructor SOPs, Akka is trying to invoke a method *by reflection* but its using the class `JobManager.class` instead of `JobManagerImpl.class`. `JobManager.class`, being an interface, will have all its methods as ***"public abstract"*** methods which is seen on your exception stack trace.

I'm not sure if there are any places you pass the `Class<?>` objects around. Check it out please.